# Alias the long repeated expression in postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way in postgresql to not repeat myself when the same expression is used in select and where blocks?

```
select (
    |/(( power((consumption_2011 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
       + power((consumption_2012 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
       + power((consumption_2013 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
    ) / 3)) as deviation
from consumption
where (
    |/(( power((consumption_2011 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
       + power((consumption_2012 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
       + power((consumption_2013 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
    ) / 3) > 0.8
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
select deviation 
from (
select 
    (( power((consumption_2011 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
      + power((consumption_2012 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
      + power((consumption_2013 - consumption_3y/3), 2)
    ) / 3) as deviation
from consumption) sub
where deviation > 0.8
```